# Switch function when click button in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to switch function when button 'historyBtn' clicked in javascript.
Here is the code:

```
const expr = '';
        var history = "document.getElementById('historyBtn'). clicked == true";
        switch (expr) {
        case history:
            allMessage();
            break;
        default:
            limit_message();
        }
```

But when i click button 'historyBtn' i cant switch function limit_message() to allMessage()

Edit:
in this case i want to run function 'limit_message' for default function, and then switch that function to allMessage when i click 'historyBtn'

Comment: Unclear what that code is supposed to do....

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first get the button element, then assign an eventListener and logs the click event:

```js
let history = document.getElementById('historyBtn');

history.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hello(ishistory) {
  if (ishistory) {
    console.log("History")
  }else{
    console.log("Limit")
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello(true)">history</button>
<button onclick="hello(false)">Limit</button>
```

Just pass a flag to function on button click like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    
    <body>
        <button id = "historyBtn" onclick="allMessage()">History</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        window.onload = limit_message();
        function allMessage (){
            alert ('In all messages - historyBtn clicked!');
        }
        
        function limit_message (){
            alert ('limit_message - onload');
        }
            
    </script>
</html>
```